# UI workflow : visually create a sequence of instructions

Tags: user-interface, workflow, task, breadcrumbs, operations

any recommendations about a user interface that let users create their own workflows (an instruction in the form of a sequence of tasks or operations) for a set of given tasks?.
I'm thinking in something where the user can drag and drop the tasks and create a linear sequence of them,  like a breadcrumb line.  I've been looking around jquery but I' very new to it.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you should provide a concrete example in order to make ir clearer.

Comment: HI,  thanks.  I want to create a visual workflow creator,  something like this [link](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/blockly/apps/maze/index.html),  which allows the user to create an ordered set of instructions,  or workflow.